# Laravel5 default pagination

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I have an error when simply put this

`->paginate(15);`

what is wrong with my code below

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator as Paginator;

class OrderController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->middleware('auth');  
    }   
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::with('customer')->get()->paginate(5);
        return view('order.index', compact('orders'));
    }

}
```

appreciate if you someone can highlight to me what have I done wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of `->get()` before the `paginate(5);` ?

Comment: You don't need `get()` when using `paginate()`.

Comment: that one I learnt from eager loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the get() when you use paginate()

```
$orders = Order::with('customer')->paginate(15);
```